# Database for regex on bigdata

Tags: regex, database, bigdata

I'am working under development of an online bioinformatic tool for sequencing data analysis. The application will handle datasets of 10^8~10^10 strings of about 100 letters (amino acid sequences). The common task for the app will be a regex search of certain strings. What database could fit such a task?

I'm looking both for relational and NoSQL DBs.

AWS Redshift seems a good option, because it is optimized for read-mostly usage (which is the case), but its price is too high.

The application will be deployed in the cloud.

Comment: Do you need a database for the regex part?  Various tools are optimized for regex searching in files, and ext4 has a 16TB file size limit.

Comment: The data consists of complex data structures with some links between entries and I need CRUD operation as well as search, so some kind of database is the only option. Also I hope to optimise some queries by indexing all N-mers (3- or 4-mers) in my target sequences to narrow the set of scanned records if request implies content of certain substring, which also far more easier to do with a database.

Comment: Perhaps you can keep the CRUD oriented meta-data in a database, and the database of sequences separate, such that each regex foreign keys back to the database.  Example in a file: `1 AGCTAAGTAC
2 TCAGACCATTA`, where the number is the sequence_id in your database.  This may simply transfer complexity from run-time to design-time, but regexing the sequences at a file level feels right to me.

Comment: I'm afraid there is none suiting your need. Just think what kind of an index you need to find any substring any length in any position. Just ideas. As there are only 4 acids, mb you don't need a "letter", but coding each acid with 2 bits is should be enough. One more idea, if your queries are similar ,e.g. you look for AAAA-CCCC, then AAAA-GGGG, then you could prepare lists containing AAAA, CCCC, GGGG. Intersect them, e.g. http://redis.io/commands/sinter, and make you full scan only against the resulting subset.

Comment: Yes, now I see your point. It might be the option, but I also thought about scalability of such database across several nodes, so the search could be distributed to reduce latency. Anyway, thank you for the idea!